# Difficulties with GPGME and Common Lisp when building an executable

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, gnupg, sbcl, gpgme

I'm working on a project in Common Lisp that uses GPGME for encryption. GPGME is installed from my distribution's repositories.

The following code works correctly when running in the repl, or if I load the file with `--load` and `--eval '(main)' --eval '(exit)'` from the command line, but when I build an executable with `sbcl --load gpgme-test.lisp --eval "(sb-ext:save-lisp-and-die #p\"test\" :toplevel #'main :executable t)"`, I get `GPGME returned error: Not operational (Unspecified source)` when running the executable.

```cl
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel)
  (ql:quickload :gpgme))

(require 'gpgme)

(defun main ()
  (gpgme:with-context (ctx)
    (print (gpgme:get-key ctx "<id here>"))))
```

I'm building the executable with sbcl's `--save-lisp-and-die option.` I've also tried building the full project using Deploy with the same results.

Comment: Did you try with an .asd system definition, defining your gpgme dependency there instead of inside your source with eval-when…ql:quickload ?

Comment: @Ehvince yes. This is just the minimal working example, the full program has the asd file.

Comment: I am keen to try with the .asd definition. BTW, where is this CL's library project page?

Comment: The lisp bindings are part of the normal GPGME project. The repo is available at https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gpgme.git;a=summary, and the CL related stuff is in lang/cl in the repository. Other than the README file, I have found no documentation for this.